# why we use this.initialState = this.state;

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can anyone explain to me please why using `this.initialState` knowing that I am using class component here in React JS ?

```
class Inscription extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      pseudo: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',

      formErrors: {}
    };

    this.initialState = this.state;

  }
```

Comment: We can't tell. Show us the entire component code - probably some of the methods are using `initialState`?!

Answer (score 2):

Imagine having a form with multiple inputs and eventually user submits all the data. After succesfull submit, you want to reset everything in the form. The easiest way is to do `this.state = this.initialState` so you don't need to define initialState two times.

Instead of adding the initialState to Class itself I would define it outside of the class.

```
const initialState = {
  pseudo: '',
  email: '',
  password: '',
  formErrors: {}
};

class Inscription extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = initialState;
  }
  onSubmit(){
    // do backend call
    // some others events
    // eventually reset the state
    this.state = initialState;
  }
}
```